# Display image after clicking on img link

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I trying to show images of the same product in different colors in a big image after clicking on a thumb. It's not a store, so I'm not using woocommerce.

I have made a custom post type called `colors-iglo` with a custom field `image` to add the second img as my thumb, and I'm using the post thumbnail to store/show the big image.

**The loop:**

```
<img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>" id="currentImg">

    <ul class="colorpicker">
      <?php
        $args = array(
          'post_type'  => 'colors-iglo',
          'orderby'    => 'date',
          'order'      => 'ASC',
          'posts_per_page' => '3'

        );

        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

        $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'images_colors', true );
      ?>

      <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="product-wrapper handles-wrapper col-12 col-xl-4">
        <div class="product-img">
          <?php
            echo '<img src=" '.$meta['image'].'" onclick="showImage(" '.the_post_thumbnail().' ") />';
           ?>
        </div><!-- .product-img -->
        <p class="product-name col-12 col-xl-12"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
      </li><!-- .product-wrapper -->

      <?php
        endwhile;
      ?>
      <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </ul>
```

**The js**

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($){

      function showImage(imgPath, imgText) {
          var curImage = document.getElementById('currentImg');

          curImage.src = imgPath;
          curImage.alt = imgText;
          curImage.title = imgText;
       }

    });
    </script>
```

**Problems I don't know how to solve:**

`<img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>" id="currentImg">` is not displaying the big image. Also I would like it to show the big image of the first color after the page is loaded.

`echo '<img src=" '.$meta['image'].'" onclick="showImage(" '.the_post_thumbnail().' ") />';` is displaying the custom field image, but also the onclick post thumb.

**Update**
[image: This is the current output]

Comment: Does it set the big image when you click on small images?

Comment: No, it does not

Comment: declare function `showImage` out of  `jQuery(function($)` scope.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the flowing in your code:

1. declare `showImage` out of `jQuery(function($)` scope.
2. trigger on click of the first thumb when document is loaded.
3. add second parameter to showImage call in your PHP script.

**JavaScript**:

```
function showImage(imgPath, imgText) {
   var curImage = document.getElementById('currentImg');
   curImage.src = imgPath;
   curImage.alt = imgText;
   curImage.title = imgText;
}

jQuery(function($){
    // trigger click on 1st image
    jQuery('.product-img').first().find('img').click();
});
```

**PHP**

replace

```
 echo '<img src=" '.$meta['image'].'" onclick="showImage(" '.the_post_thumbnail().' ") />';
```

with

```
 echo '<img src=" '.$meta['image'].'" onclick="showImage(\' '.the_post_thumbnail().'\', \'\')"/>';
```

Comment: should the `<img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>" id="currentImg">` stay outside the loop ? It gives an empty `img src`. And how to hide the onclick from being visible above the `$meta['image']` ?

Comment: If the current page have no thumbnail, insert `<img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>" id="currentImg">`  inside the loop. But check to be called only at first iteration. Can you explain also what do you mean by "hide the onclick...."?

Comment: I have updated my question with an image of the current output

Comment: When I insert it in the loop it outputs all the big images

Comment: In my comment i wrote you to check if the first iteration is going when you do output. So the big image will be shown only once.